# How to correctly write MySQL query for UPDATE?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to perform a query using `sequelize` but with row query method. It looks like this:

```
        try {
            const res = await db.query(
                `
                SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
                UPDATE
                    \`demo-shop.com_visits\`
                SET
                    visitDate = visitDate + 1800000;
                SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
                `
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
```

In Workbenck it works, but in executing it gives an error:

> 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near \'UPDATE\n

I can't find an error. Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you using `mysql` module for connection library , you can pass `multipleStatements: true` from sequelize.

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(dbname, username, pass, {
    host: host,
    port: port,
    dialectOptions: {
          multipleStatements: true
    }

});
```